# Neo4J Error while importing huge database

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases

i wanted to try NEO4J with the Musicbrainz database from the example datasets https://neo4j.com/developer/example-data/#_data_sets.
I downloaded the 4.4GB big file archive and dezipped the hole database to a new .graphdb folder next to my other databases like "default.graphdb". When i now try to start the database after sucessfully opened it i get the following error:

```
>     Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@7d7bed25' was
> successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
> cause exception "The node label update contained unsorted label ids
> [17, 9]".
```

How do i resolve this error. Or is there a smarter way to import the data of this database.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Not sure this will work but you should try using the `allow_store_upgrade` option in your neo4j.conf.  It could be that the version you're running and the version of the database backup are out of sync.  Make sure you're using a recent version and try that, include the results here.